# Can not set current light/dark mode into local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage, darkmode

I am a javascript beginner and I am trying to integrate a simple light mode button. The default for my website is the dark mode. So the JS/CSS dark and light mode works fine. If the light mode is activated, the whole (external) CSS will be just replaced and it looks really great.

However here is my problem; The current mode of the CSS is not saved in the local storage. So when the user moves to the next HTML page, the default dark mode is back again.

I have already found many (really many) articles/forum posts etc. and tested a lot of sample codes (combined them etc.) but none of them worked for me.

Here is my JS code and a small part of my HTML/CSS. I've broken it up into individual snippets, because I assume that the snippet cannot visualize multiple HTML/CSS files, so you probably have to save and edit the pages locally.

Of course my question is; what do I need to change in the code so that the current Dark/LightMode setting is stored in the local storage and accessed on a page switch/reload etc.?

Thanks a lot for your effort in advance! :)

````css
```
 /* This is the light mode css */
 
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
}
h2 {
font-size: 20px;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
.btn-toggle {
background: white;
}

```
````

````css
```

 /* This is the dark mode css */
 
body {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
h1 {
font-size: 30px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
}
h2 {
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
.btn-toggle {
background: white;
}

```
````

````html
```

<!-- this is the first HTML page --> 

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="darkmode.css" id="theme-link">
   
</head>

<body>

<h1>Toggle Dark/lightmode example</h1>

<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle dark/light</button>
<a href="test2.html"><button>Go to Site 2</button></a>

<h2>Unnecessary content</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="darkmode.js"></script>

```
````

````html
```

<!-- this is the second page -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="darkmode.css" id="theme-link">
   
</head>

<body>

<h1>Toggle Dark/lightmode example</h1>

<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle dark/light</button>
<a href="test1.html"><button>Go back to Site 1</button></a>

<h2>Unnecessary content</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="darkmode.js"></script>

<script>

// The JS file is usually eternally linked

// Select the button
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
// Select the stylesheet <link>
const theme = document.querySelector("#theme-link");
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
} else if (currentTheme == "light") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
}
// Listen for a click on the button
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // If the current URL contains "dark-theme.css"
  if (theme.getAttribute("href") == "kiblsstyle.css") {
// ... then switch it to "light-theme.css"
theme.href = "kiblsstylelight.css";
  // Otherwise...
  } else {
// ... switch it to "dark-theme.css"
theme.href = "kiblsstyle.css";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

```
````

Comment: have you searched on Google or YouTube for tutorials before asking here?

Comment: @Kunal Tanwar Yes, I have watched several YT-Tutorials also the one of Kevin Powell what was recommended here on Stackoverflow, but I need an external CSS that is completely replaced, so I can not adopt it 1 to 1 but must somehow tinker something together that works. Also the tutorial from css-tricks dot com I have read completely and could take over very much but it also does not fit as I want/need it. Not to mention the many posts I have gone through here on Stackoverflow (and other sites). :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn´t try storing whole html element in local storage. Instead try storing theme name and then conditionally apply theme that you find in local storage. Here is your JS after clean up:

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");

const styleLink = document.querySelector("#theme-link");

// Get stored theme with fallback value
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";

if (currentTheme === "dark") styleLink.href = "kiblsstyle.css";
else if (currentTheme === "light") styleLink.href = "kiblsstylelight.css";

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (styleLink.getAttribute("href") !== "kiblsstyle.css") {
        styleLink.href = "kiblsstyle.css";
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    } else {
        styleLink.href = "kiblsstylelight.css";
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is "almost" what I wanted to achieve. But here is still the problem when I activate the light mode, the next page is still loaded by default in dark mode. If I switch also the next page to light mode and switch back and forth between page 1 and 2, the selection remains saved. So if I have 30 html pages, I have to activate the lightmode once on all 30 pages, so that the lightmode is at the end saved on all pages. This is quite time consuming. Is it not possible to use the storage for each of the following pages so that I do not have to switch each page individually until it is stored?

Comment: Hm... with me it behaves somehow differently. I have to activate the light mode on each page. But then it is saved in the local storage and accessed correct when i reload the page but if I want to switch back to dark mode, I have to switch it back again for each single page until it is saved everywhere. Am I doing something wrong? But I just copy and paste your code... :/

Comment: For bigger projects, as you mention 30+ pages, it would make sense to use a framework like Angular or React for easier maintenance. I´m not sure what you mean by activate, but there shouldn´t be an issue in fetching from local storage current theme on each JS. Not where the issue mentioned comes from but if you share your github repo I can take a look.

Comment: Hm, now that is interesting. The problem I described only seems to occur with the local files. Once I uploaded it to the server, it works without problems as you describe it. Well, then my problem has actually solved. So; thank you very much and have a great evening! :)

Answer (score 0):

localStorage was created to save simple, prinitive values and isn't intended to store DOM-elements. So you can just save boolean value in your case with just 2 themes. (When you'll create more of them, use few buttons or array, etc.) Or switch theme title but don't use DOM-object

[localStorage article](https://gomakethings.com/saving-html-to-localstorage-with-vanilla-js/#save-the-html-to-localstorage)

```
const theme = document.querySelector("#theme-link");
const currentLightTheme = localStorage.getItem("isLight") || true;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!currentLightTheme) {
        theme.setAttribute('href', 'kiblsstylelight.css');
    } else {
        theme.setAttribute('href', 'kiblsstyle.css');
    }
    localStorage.setItem('isLight', !currentLightTheme)
 });
```

Comment: I am sorry, but your code somehow doesn't work at all. As soon as it is integrated, everything stops working. :/