# Switch to dark mode button

Tags: javascript, darkmode

I have a template that sets dark mode only adding a class to the body.
This template does not include a toggle button so I am trying to create it by myself but it goes back to light theme when I go to another file or reload the page.

I am using a button and this JS code

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
button.onclick = function(){
body.classList.toggle('dark-layout');
}
```

The problem is how can I save this settings, because once you reload it turns to the values set by default.
I am sure there should be a front-end solution, but the only way I think is to create a table in a db and set the class inside an if and the button will be switching this value

Comment: have you try local storage or other front persistence mechanism ?

Comment: store in local storage, backend, or a cookie

Comment: Use JS Local Storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: FYI don't use querySelector to get the `body`, use `document.body`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not set current light/dark mode into local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662122/can-not-set-current-light-dark-mode-into-local-storage) Down vote because this exact question gets asked at least once a month. Please research before asking.

Answer (score 2):

A simplest solution is to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store settings.

```js
//read stored setting on startup
let isDarkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkmode");
//apply setting
setDarkMode();

button.onclick = function(){
  isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
  setDarkMode(isDarkMode);
}
function setDarkMode(value = isDarkMode)
{
  value = ~~value; //convert to integer
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-layout', value);
  localStorage.setItem("darkmode", value);
}
```

Comment: I tried and looks like works better, but now when I load any page it turns into dark theme by default

Comment: Any pages on the same website that use this javascript...why would you expect anything else?

Comment: This script is being included in all files with php

Comment: Oh, I see, "by default" is when you visit website for the first time... I've updated the answer, added `value = ~~value;` it should fix it.